# Flutter FireStore query get document 's collection

Tags: firebase, flutter

i have collection called groups inside it there are more than one documents and each document has some files one the files is called "special" a boolean now inside each document we have files collection 
only one document will have the special set to true 
how can query only the files of the 'special' document

```
Firestore.instance
          .collection('groups')
          .document("english")
          .collection("groups")
          .where('special', isEqualTo: true)
                      .snapshots(),
```

this will get me only the document but i want the files collection of the document
so i have to do another hit ?
thanks[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot of the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should hit

```
Firestore.instance
          .collection('groups')
          .document("english")
          .collection("files")
```

if i understood correctly your demand